# Kubernetes/Helm - contributing configuration from one chart to a component in another

Tags: kubernetes, helm

Our applications are organized as follows:

- A single "core" set of services deployed by a `core` Helm chart
- Several individual applications deployed by their own Helm charts

  - Let's call these A, B and C

So the normal install order is:

`helm install core`

`helm install A` ... followed by B and C, but you might not have the entire alphabet on any given installation.

I have a shared component deployed by the `core` chart and I want each of the app charts A, B and C to be able to contribute configuration to that component.

I know I could specify an annotation to go on Kubernetes `configMap`s and have the core component set up a Kubernetes watch or scan periodically for new configMaps, but I'd prefer not to have to build Kubernetes knowledge into that component.

If the configuration was a single configMap, I could mount it into the core component's pod as a file/directory of files and that would be fine. However, it can't be a single configMap because multiple charts (A, B and C) need to optionally contribute to it.

Is there a way to achieve this pattern without the core component calling Kubernetes APIs to look up its configuration?

Comment: Having just found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49898261/volume-mounted-configmap-by-label-selector I'm starting to think the answer is "No" but that is quite a few years old so let's see what people come up with.